# Sl4j doesn't log sql statements from JPA

Tags: java, jpa, slf4j, show-sql

I'm developing an app with JPA, Hibernate and Sl4j. I can'm make my sl4j to log sql statements.

Here is my code:

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="timeoffcore.persistence.unit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=timeoff.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
```

But there are no sql statements in log. Neither in console, nor in file.

Comment: Here is my **spring.xml**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

property name should be:

```
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
```

in `persistence.xml`

Add below entry in `log4.properties`

```
# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

Comment: <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

helped me, even without log4j properties you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should add several lines to log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

And two more lines into  persistence.xml as well

```
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

I hope it helps